# Admin user column sort by numeric meta key

Tags: admin, user-meta, sort

I try to sort a custom user field (team_user_id), I have all data but I can’t sort by numeric.

**updated code**

```
add_filter('manage_users_columns', [$this, 'custom_id_column']);
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', [$this, 'custom_id_content'], 10, 3);

add_filter('pre_get_posts', [$this, 'sort_content']);

public function custom_id_column($columns)
{
  foreach ($columns as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === 'username') {
      $new_columns['ID'] = __('ID', 'default');
    }
    $new_columns[$k] = $v;
  }
  return $new_columns;
}

public function custom_id_content($value, $column_name, $user_id)
{
  $user = get_userdata($user_id);
  if ('ID' == $column_name) {
    return get_user_meta($user->ID, 'team_member_ID', true);
  }
  return $value;
}

public function sort_content($vars){
  if ( isset($vars['orderby'] && 'team_member_id' === $var['orderby']) {
    $vars = array_merge($vars, 
    array( 'meta_key' => 'team_member_id',
           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' 
    ));
  }
  retunrn $vars
}
```

I tried in pre_get_post and request, but result is unsorted

Comment: Are you sure this code runs? It might help to paste the rest of your code, and what $vars looks like after the array_merge

Comment: updated code with full function create col, insert data col and sorting

team_member_id is user meta key

Comment: Resolve with add_filter pre_get_users